# how to get event name in combobox DHTMLX scheduler

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, scheduler, dhtmlx

i m using DHTMLX scheduler. i want to display events based on search criteria. i coded for filtering events bt i m unable to get event name in combobox from database. how i can retrieve event names from mysql on front page.

my code for filtering event

```
scheduler.filter_week = function(id, event)
{
    if(event.name == 'New event')
        return false; // event will be filtered (not rendered)
        //or
        return true; // event will be rendered
}
```

how to retrieve event name ? any suggestions ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to archive? How to load data/items in your combobox from you server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a server-side search, you have to reload scheduler events each time search value has changed

```
function search(value){
    scheduler.clearAll();

    scheduler.load("data source url" + "?search=" + encodeURIComponent(value));
   //you may need to handle scenario when user has already typed some other criteria, by the time data is loaded
}
```

And do appropriate search on the server based on 'search' request parameter. 
If you use such approach, you may not need client-side filters.

However, if you load all events to the page initially, client-side search could be much more responsive, as user won't have to wait until each new portion of data is loaded.

```
function search(value){

    scheduler.filter_week = function(id, event){
        var haystack = (event.name || "").toLowerCase(),
            needle = (value || "").toLowerCase();

        return haystack.indexOf(needle) != -1;
    }

    scheduler.setCurrentView();
}
```